# Play MP4 video format with videotag in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, video, mp4, html5-video

I'm sure its' play, because Instagram does, and the only format is mp4 occupying.
But I can not give what the trick is to do to play.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `<video>` tag.

You can find Mozzila documentation for playing media [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video).

Answer (score 0):

FireFox does not support MP4 video natively.  You will need to use flash to play MP4s in FireFox.  JWPlayer and VideoJS are two good videoplayers with Flash fallback.

To be able to play video in ALL browsers, in my experience, you will need mp4 AND webm or ogv formats.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video

H.264 is MP4.

Answer (score 0):

### you only need to install Windows Media Feature Pack-of your OS

**1**. download link (85MB) :https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42503

**1.1**---or search for your windows version media pack .

**2**. use code

```
<video controls="" width="auto">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="video-name.mp4">
    <embed src="video-name.mp4" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="auto" height="auto"></video>
```